# =CS50 PSET 2 CAESAR= How do I convert the key to digit? It gives me this error if I use atoi()

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I'm having a problem with `atoi()` in the `only_digits` function. I asked on discord and they said that I am passing a char type arg to `atoi()` which doesn't work since `atoi()` only takes string or char * (array of char) as arguments. I don't get it. I'm confused with the difference of string and char. Aren't I passing `argv[1]` (which is a string) to `only_digits`? Which means `inputKey` is a string as well? So what do they mean that I am passing a char type arg to `atoi()`? How exactly do I make `atoi()` work? I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days now.

```
// Encrypts text using Caesar's cipher
// ci = (pi + k) % 26

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool only_digits (string inputKey);
char rotate (char plaintext[], int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string p;

    // Make sure program was run with just one command-line argument

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Enter exactly one input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Make sure every character in argv[1] is a digit (DOESN'T WORK)

    /*else if (only_digits(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }*/

    else
    {
        p = get_string("plaintext: ");
    }

    // Convert argv[1] from a string to an int

    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    char c[strlen(p) + 1];

    // Convert ASCII range down to a value from 0 to 25



    // For each character in the plaintext: (DOESN'T WORK)

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i <= n; i++)
    {
        // Rotate the character if it's a letter // ci = (pi + k) % 26

        if (isalpha(p[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(p[i]))
            {
                c[i] = ((p[i]) + k) % 26;
            }
            else if (islower(p[i]))
            {
                c[i] = ((p[i]) + k) % 26;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", c);
}

// Function to encrypt plaintext

/*char rotate (char plaintext[], int key)
{
    char c[strlen(plaintext) + 1];

    return c;
}*/

// Function to check if key is a digit (DOESN'T WORK)

bool only_digits (string inputKey)
{
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(inputKey); i < n; i++)
    {
        // Converts string input to int

        int response = atoi(inputKey[i]);

        // Check if it is a digit

        if (!(isdigit(response)))
        {
            flag++;
        }
    }

    if (flag != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: syntax error]

Comment: `isdigit(response)`?  `response` is already an `int` value.  `isdigit()` is for checking if a `char` value is a digit **character**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I deleted `int response = atoi(inputKey[i]);` and replaced the if condition with `if (!(isdigit(inputKey)))`. Now it compiles but if I try to run it, it gives me the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What is happening?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I replaced `if (!(isdigit(inputKey)))` with `if (!(isdigit(atoi(inputKey))))`. I also changed the last if-else condition with `if (flag == 0) { return false; } else { return true; }` but it prints `Usage: ./caesar key` even if what I entered is a digit.

Comment: You need to use `if (!isdigit(inputKey[i])) return false;` in the loop and just `return true;` after the loop. Since `inputKey` is a `char *`, `inputKey[i]` is a `char` — and `qtoi()` expects a `char *`.

Comment: Also, don't post images of text — put the text directly into the question, preceded by a line containing `\`\`\`none` and followed by a line containing `\`\`\``.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! `if (!isdigit(inputKey[i]))` worked. But I used `return false` instead of `true` after the loop since I don't want the program to print `Usage: ./caesar key` if the key is a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Strings* in C are defined as a sequence of nonzero bytes (characters), followed by a null-terminating byte:

```
char str[] = "hello"; /* in memory: { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' } */
```

[`atoi`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) (*ASCII to integer*) expects a proper null-terminated *string* (`char *`). You can not pass it a single `char`.

```
int number = atoi("1672387");
```

[`isdigit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3.html) expects a single *character*.

```
int is_true = isdigit('5');
```

---

In your program `inputKey[i]` is a single *character*. You can test it directly with `isdigit`, there is no need to convert it to an integer representation beforehand.

You can also simply return early if you encounter a non-digit character.

```
bool only_digits(string inputKey) {
    for (size_t i = 0, length = strlen(inputKey); i < length; i++)
        if (!isdigit(inputKey[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

*Note: `size_t` is the return type of `strlen`, and the most appropriate type for indexing memory.*

Comment: Thanks! I now understand how to use `atoi()` and `isdigit()`.